# My "shell:startup" is contaminated. What is it exactly?

Tags: windows

I got click-baited and stupidly installed malware packages yesterday. Today I found out it even contaminated my windows startup service so I went on and start cleaning things.

One thing I noticed is that when I RUN(win+r) `shell:startup`, it redirected me to a directory where malware files once were. So I deleted the directory, but I feel like I have to fix that global variable too.

*update: My taskmngr's `start program` tab is now empty.

What is "shell:startup" and where can I fix its content path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question:

Go to Registry Editor (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `regedit`, then press Enter)

Follow this path

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User
> Shell Folders

Find the `Startup` string, right click on it and modify the path with the correct one:

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

---

To modify the startup path for all users startup you have to edit the `Common Startup` string following this path:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders

The default location is:

`%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

**Please remember to restart your device after.**

---

You should also check out this:

[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)